# How to install nodejs on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, laravel-5, npm

I install Ubuntu 16.04 on VPS.

My framework is laravel 5.6.

Upload my project on /var/www/html

After run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` this code, show this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 132 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/12.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 62.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "fa_IR",
    LC_MONETARY = "fa_IR",
    LC_ADDRESS = "fa_IR",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "fa_IR",
    LC_NAME = "fa_IR",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "fa_IR",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "fa_IR",
    LC_NUMERIC = "fa_IR",
    LC_PAPER = "fa_IR",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 73714 files and directories currently     installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_9.11.1-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (9.11.1-1nodesource1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up nodejs (9.11.1-1nodesource1) ...
```

And run `node -v` show this error:

```
node: error while loading shared libraries: libuv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to install npm and node on ubuntu 16.4 without error?

Comment: whats your user?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth Hi, I use SSH for connect to VPS

Comment: i think you might need to log to root user

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using the [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation), it works on many barebones systems as well, and will let you further troubleshoot the specific issues related to that version of Node. AFAICT the specific error you're seeing is related to the particular snapshot of 16.**04** (not 16.4) that you are using regarding a common C library. I would suggest two things to resolve this if using a different Node version doesn't already solve this:

1. Google the shared object to find what Ubuntu library is needed, and perhaps installation of that may solve it.
2. If it's already installed or the error persists, you may need to adjust your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and other C-level env variables during installation to refer to the location of the library.
3. Contact your OS admin or cloud provider to discuss solutions for the missing object.

Comment: Hi, I do not understand what you mean! Is there another way?

Comment: Hi @Ele can you please describe the line or sentence of my suggestion that you'd like me to elaborate on?

Comment: My English is not very good. Sorry, I do not understand much about you

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to node, but to your ubuntu that is misconfigured. Run

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8  #### ---> or the locale you are actually using
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

to configure your system's locales. After that, uninstall nodejs

```
sudo apt remove --purge nodejs
```

Now, follow the advice on [nodejs' website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) on how to install nodejs via package managers. To install node, do the following:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Now you'll have a working ubuntu (at least for the related parts), and nodejs

Comment: Hi , Afetr run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` show this error : `perl: warning: Setting locale failed. and ...`

Comment: How to issue this problem?

Comment: Try to reinstall the language pack you are using. You can also try to run sudo apt install —reinstall language-pack-<your language> @Ele

Comment: After install nodejs, I run `node -v`. show this error: `node: error while loading shared libraries: libuv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` How to issue this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **nvm** (Node Version Manager) you can install it from the terminal

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

It will set all the environment for you (like to enable the **node** command in the terminal, same for **npm**) and the **nvm** let you download and change de current version of Nodejs in your device in very simple way which is a very good feature, considering that the node have a high update frequency.

Comment: Hi , Just run this code? `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
`

Comment: Yeah, just run it on terminal, the complete documentation is here: [https://github.com/creationix/nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: Thanks, After run this code,  I run node -v. show this error: node: error while loading shared libraries: libuv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory How to issue this problem?

Comment: It seems to be a problem to find a shared lib of the Ubuntu, I made a research and found this possible solution: try to run `sudo ldconfig` on terminal

Comment: I run `sudo ldconfig` but after run `node -v` show this error: `node: error while loading shared libraries: libuv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` :-(

Comment: It seems that the OS is missing this `libuv.so.1` file. Have a look at this page: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libuv it seems that you can install it manually, I'm not sure though

Answer (score 0):

I resolve nodejs installation on ubuntu 18.04 Bionic with this task:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add this lines:

```
#newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe multiverse
```

$sudo apt update

$sudo apt upgrade

$sudo apt install nodejs

$node -v

$sudo apt install npm